# Group SID's slow to resolve on Server 2016 (workgroup server, not on a domain)

Tags: windows, sid

Anytime I go to the security tab on this new Server 2016 machine it takes over 20 seconds for the custom group SID's to resolve to their local names. Usernames, however, resolve almost instantly, as do built-in groups "SYSTEM", "Administrators", "Users". I have noticed that for some people this issue is related to DNS configuration on their AD setup, however this is a simple stand-alone file server that is not part of a domain or a domain controller. The DNS entries for this server for its two NIC's point to the local router.

The same problem also shows up any time I try to add new share permissions as well, basically it seems to happen anytime a permissions list is displayed that has a local group added to the permissions list. This makes it very difficult to change permissions.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try to disconnect the server from the network and check if it's still slow ? (disable all the network adapters)

Comment: Unfortunately no, I am connecting remotely. I might be able to try that later tomorrow.

Comment: I can verify that our other machine, running windows 2012 and setup similarly, displays the same behavior.  It takes longer with more custom groups being added to the permissions list. During this time the window is unresponsive, ie I can't even click "cancel".  1 custom group = 8 second delay, 2 custom groups = 21 second delay, 3 custom groups = 28 second delay

Comment: What's the server's general performance and/or CPU utilization? What about anti-virus? Can you temporarily disable A/V and see if that has any effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a NETBIOS timeout, if you are using DNS and not NETBIOS (I hope so...) you should consider disabling it on your servers (after testing) :

In the properties of your network adapters, select "Internet Protocol Version 4" -> Properties -> select the "WINS" tab -> Disable NetBIOS over TCP/IP.

Try to open the Security tab again (you don't need to restart) and it should load faster.

Comment: Yes, manually disabling NetBIOS over tcp cut the down by more than half. It was set to "default". Thanks!